# Programatically changing a FieldArray value in Redux-Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to figure out how to use `this.props.dispatch(change)` in order use one field selector value to update another fields value within a FieldArray.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2p7k7jn930

I can't seem to get the syntax in this correct.

```
this.props.dispatch(
        change("FieldArraysForm", `${props.member}.firstName`, this.props.hasLastName)
      );
```

Any thoughts? Expected behavior would be to add a member and then have anything typed into the Last Name field be programmatically updated in the First Name field.

```
/**
The following can replace the file in the Field Arrays example
(https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/tree/master/examples/fieldArrays) to demonstrate this functionality.
**/
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  Field,
  FieldArray,
  reduxForm,
  formValueSelector,
  change
} from "redux-form";
import validate from "./validate";

const selector = formValueSelector("fieldArrays");

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);

class Member extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, props) {
    if (this.props.hasLastName !== prevProps.hasLastName) {
      this.props.dispatch(
        change("FieldArraysForm", `${props.member}.firstName`, this.props.hasLastName)
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { member, index, fields, hasLastName } = this.props;
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Member"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />
        <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.firstName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="First Name"
        />
        <Field
          name={`${member}.lastName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Last Name"
        />
        {hasLastName && <p>{hasLastName}</p>}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
Member = connect((state, props) => ({
  hasLastName: selector(state, `${props.member}.lastName`)
}))(Member);

const renderMembers = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
        Add Member
      </button>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </li>
    {fields.map((member, index) => (
      <Member member={member} fields={fields} index={index} key={index} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const FieldArraysForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="clubName"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Club Name"
      />
      <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers} />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "fieldArrays", // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access the `FieldArray` dynamically, you would want to change this:

```
change("FieldArraysForm", `${props.member}.firstName`, this.props.hasLastName)
```

to this:

```
change("FieldArraysForm", `members[${this.props.index}].firstName`, this.props.hasLastName)
```

Also, pass in the form `selector` specified:

```
const selector = formValueSelector("fieldArrays");
```

This would give you:

```
change("fieldArrays", `members[${this.props.index}].firstName`, this.props.hasLastName)
```

Had to get some help on this one - thanks goes to @Amanda Field.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the index of the field in `FieldArray` you want to change. To do so, just use `<fieldName>.<index>.<propertyName>`, for instance:

`this.props.change('members.0.firstName', 'Donald')`

where *member* is the name of your `FieldArray` field, *0* is the index of the item in the array you want to change and *firstName* is the property of the object.
See sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2xo0rj4oqp)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry I should have mentioned that I was already able to make it work by hard coding the value. I'm wondering how to make it dynamic.... So if for instance there are 4 field arrays created how would I handle dynamically making the selectors and adding the change dispatches accordingly.

Comment: Any thoughts on this @Dario right now its become a bit of a show stopper for us?